# SocketServer AttributeError: Instance has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, serversocket

I have an issue with this mini game that i made which i am trying to add to a server.

I am trying to print a function from an instance of a Character but i'm not sure how to pass the proper function in.
This is what i have:

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
  Class Character():
    name = ""
    age = 0

  Class Human(Character):
    locationX = 0
    locationY = 0
    def help(self):
      self.request.send("Q to Quit")

  class Boy(Character, Human):
    def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name
      age = 10

  def handle(self):
    p1 = self.Boy("Jim")

    self.request.send(":")
    command = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    if command == "help":
      p1.help()
```

My error is:

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 649, in __init__
      self.handle()
    File "rpg.py", line 281, in handle
      p1.help()
    File "rpg.py", line 23, in help
      self.request.send("Q to Quit")
    AttributeError: Boy instance has no attribute 'request'
```

Can someone explain why this is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've chosen to have your classes `Character` &c **embedded** within class `ThreadedTCPRequestHandler` -- but embedded is very different from **derived from**.  The embedded classes have no special access to the `self` of the class in which they're embedded!

So you need to enrich e.g `Character` with an `__init__` that takes the `handler` instance creating it:

```
  class Character():
      def __init__(self, handler):
          self.name = ""
          self.age = 0
          self.handler = handler
```

(I've also taken the opportunity to make name and age **instance** variables, which makes more sense, and change indents to standard 4 characters vs the 2 you used:-).

Subclasses must then call the base class's `__init__` appropriately:

```
  class Boy(Character, Human):
      def __init__(self, name, handler):
          Character.__init__(self, handler)
          self.name = name
          self.age = 10
```

and the creation of new instances must also go along:

```
  def handle(self):
      p1 = self.Boy("Jim", handler=self)
      # etc etc
```

(the `handler=` part here is just for clarity and readability, not strictly needed for functionality:-).

The overall architecture is now peculiar (embedded classes are rarely used in Python) but at least it will work!-)

Comment: Wow, thank you! That makes more sense. 
1 more question, if embedded classes are rarely used, how would one go about creating the same thing but without it embedded? Would i have to have everything outside ThreadedHandler?
Just asking for future reference.

Comment: You'd move all the now-embedded `class` statements outside of the `class ThreadedHandler` statement and lose the `self.` in `p1 = self.Boy("Jim", self)`.  Having the classes "outside" makes it far easier to write unit tests for your code -- and copious unit tests are more than a "best practice", they're the **only** practice you should *ever* consider!-)